# How to validate a file for non-blank lines and non-comment lines in makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

I want to validate sample.x for non-blank lines and non-comment lines in makefile, if validation passes it should print successful and if not it should exit the execution.

I'm trying with the below code but unable to succeed.

```
validate=$(sed "/^\s*$/d" ${TEX_FILENAME} | sed "/^ *%/d;s/%.*//" | wc -l)
if [ "${validate}" -gt 0 ];\
then\
  echo "    validate success";\
else\
  echo "    validate not successfull";\
  echo;\
  exit 2;\
fi
```

Comment: you can execute a rule with a shell command in it e.g.: contents := $(shell grep -c "^$" same.x),  where grep -c "^$" will count the blank lines. you could put this in a script and get that working first.

Comment: it is not working, when I try to execute it is giving me validation not successful even the file has uncommented lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a number of problems, complications, and bugs here.

In a Makefile, you need to double any dollar signs you want to be passed through to the shell.

Your `sed` probably does not understand the regex dialect you are trying to use.

Having a script tell you "failure" is kind of moot when the purpose of `make` is to tell you when something failed.

Counting whether the number of matches is zero is a silly antipattern.  Just check if there are any matches. Most regex tools will exit with a non-zero result code when they fail to find a match, which is precisely what `make` keeps an eye on (though `sed` doesn't actually do this; but we don't really need `sed` here).

```
validate: ${TEX_FILENAME}
    grep -q -v -e '^[[:space:]]*$$' -e '^[[:space:]]*%' $<
```

If `make` doesn't stop, the file was valid.  Maybe add a comment above the `grep` command if you are afraid you'll forget what this was for.

If you want to use Perl regex, maybe see if your system has `grep -P` (but understand that this is not portable) or simply rewrite this in Perl.

Comment: How can I print a message if success using this code

Comment: That's pretty useless but you can add `&& echo Success` at the end of the command.

Comment: Can I use the condition in if statement as the above is printing in terminal which executing the make file.

Comment: `cmd && foo || bar` is shorthand for `if cmd; then foo; else bar; fi`

Comment: When I tried below code 
@if latex $(BASENAME).tex ;\
      then\
      echo 1. latex (1) successful;\
  else \
      echo 1. latex (1) failed;\
      echo \
  fi
I'm getting below error
/bin/sh: -c: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 2: `      echo 1. latex (1) successful;\'
make: *** [latex1] Error 1

Comment: You need to use quotes around the strings you `echo`; it works fine without quotes if the strings don't contain shell metacharacters but that is not the case here. Also, tangentially, don't use `@` at least while debugging, and in fact pretty much ever except perhaps before completely trivial commands.

Comment: Try http://shellcheck.net/ for debugging trivial shell syntax problems.

Comment: while trying to exit the code when error occurred, I'm unable to exit the code. I'm using exit 2; command

Comment: It's not clear from your comment where `exit 2` is failing. I'll repeat my recommendation to not complicate things just to get a human-readable message. If you really can't figure it out, post a new question with enough details.